# Loading Data into Rstudio

Tags: r, loading, readr

What am I doing wrong in this?

```
library(readr)
source.data= (file.path("C", "User","Administrator", "Documents","Classes","Fall_2018","Econ380"))
"weather <- read_rds'(file.path(source.data, VirginiaWeather2017.rds))
```

> Error: unexpected string constant in
>
> Error: Incomplete expression: weather <- read_rds'(file.path(source.data,CollegeParkWeather2017.rds))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow and R. There is a typo in that `readr::read_rds`---the extra apostrophe. Also, you would need to wrap the `rds` object in double quotes, and put a colon after the `C`.

How does the following work?

```
library(readr)
source.data <- 
  file.path("C:", "User", "Administrator", "Documents", "Classes", "Fall_2018", "Econ380")
weather <- read_rds(file.path(source.data, "VirginiaWeather2017.rds"))
```

Let me know if that did not do the trick.

Comment: I get this error even after changing directory to desktop

Comment: Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:/User/Administrator/Desktop/VirginiaWeather2017.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Well... chances are that the file path is wrong or the file name wrong, so that there is actually "no such file or directory.".